# How can I resolve Ionic Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "." when adding new page?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ionic3, angular6

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."

```
    at webpackMissingModule (index.js:3)
    at e.code (index.js:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ee3a374a94c4cd74e2a6:54)
    at Object.256 (main.ts:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ee3a374a94c4cd74e2a6:54)
    at Object.233 (main.js:412)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ee3a374a94c4cd74e2a6:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap ee3a374a94c4cd74e2a6:25)
    at main.js:1
```

Before adding new `bookmarks` pages in app, the app working perfectly fine, After adding `bookmarks` pages  i'm getting `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."`

Here is my setup

```
Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Angular Core: 5.2.11
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
Node: 8.11.1
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { BookmarksPage} from'../pages/bookmarks/bookmarks';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ContactPage,
    BookmarksPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ContactPage,
    BookmarksPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
    ]
  })
export class AppModule {}
```

**bookmarks.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
selector: 'page-bookmarks',
templateUrl: 'bookmarks.html'
 })
export class BookmarksPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}
```

[index.js in developer console](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gZnVUsjprTLszfkYAJq2nyZeAowBJhDG)

I've tried to clear cache and `npm rebuild` also.
In the build (`ionic serve`) process there is no errors. But in the browser i'm getting Cannot find module, i really want to understand what is going on here

Comment: Have you imported `MyApp` into `app.module.ts` file?

Comment: Yes I did imported

Comment: `from '../pages/bookmarks/bookmarks'`. Try adding space after `from` keyword in `app.module` imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out, when creating the project from `ionic cli` the `IonicPageModule` was missing on the project.

Adding `IonicPageModule` manually in project and running command `npm run-script` fixed the issue.

> Solution

- **app-module.ts**

  ```
  import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage)
  ],
  ```
- **`npm run-script build`**

NOTE: `IonicPageModule` is an `NgModule` that bootstraps a child `IonicPage` in order to set up routing.

PS: Still dint know how that worked, but that worked. Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `umd` from the import

change

```
 import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/umd';
```

to

```
 import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

check [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4921) for more details.

Comment: Ohh sorry i didn't have `umd` but still getting same issue. i updated the question. In ionic startup app that uses `import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/umd'; ` what is the logic behind remove `umd'